# Hibernate Jsp Servlet registration form doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jsp, servlets

When i run the app, my data is not being put into my database, I don't know what's the problem, i would appriciate some help. This is my hibernate util:

```
    public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
                Properties settings = new Properties();
                settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb");
                settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
                settings.put(Environment.PASS, "theworldismine");
                settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

                settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

                settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

                settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

                configuration.setProperties(settings);
                configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

                ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                    .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
                sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                return sessionFactory;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
```

This is my user controller:

```
    public class UserController {

    private userDao userdao;

    public void init() {
        userdao = new userDao();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        register(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/registration.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    private void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
        String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setPassword(password);

        userdao.saveUser(user);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("register-success.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

This is my userDao:

```
    public class userDao {
    public void saveUser(User user){

        Transaction tx= null;

        try{
          Session session= HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

          session.save(user);
        }catch(Exception e){

        if(tx!=null){
        tx.rollback();

        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>validate1</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>validate1</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>validate1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/validate1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file> register.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget transaction:

```
try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession())
{
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.save(user);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```